# Is Simple Query Search compatible with shingles?

Tags: elasticsearch, shingles

I am wondering if it is possible to use shingles with the Simple Query String query. My mapping for the relevant field looks like this:

```
{
    "text_2": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer"
    }
}
```

The analyzer and filters are defined as follows:

```
"analyzer": {
    "shingle_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": ["standard", "custom_delimiter", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball", "filter_shingle"]
    }
},
"filter": {
    "filter_shingle":{
       "type":"shingle",
       "max_shingle_size":5,
       "min_shingle_size":2,
       "output_unigrams":"true"
    },
    "custom_delimiter": {
        "type": "word_delimiter",
        "preserve_original": True
    }
}
```

I am performing the following search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer",
                        "fields": [
                            "text_2"
                        ],
                        "lenient": "false",
                        "default_operator": "and",
                        "query": "porsches small red"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a document with text_2 = `small red porsches`. Since I am using the AND operator, I would expect my document to NOT match, since the above query should produce a shingle of "porsches small red", which is a different order. However, when I look at the match explanation I am only seeing the single word tokens "red" "small" "porsche", which of course match.

Is SQS incompatible with shingles?

Comment: I think It could be done but what is your min shingle size? even if you use match query it will match, what exactly is your goal? what should match and what should not?

Comment: How does the analyzer for the `text_2` field look like in your mapping, is it the standard one? Can you share your index settings and mappings?

Comment: I've updated the question with that information.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Yes, but...".

What you're seeing is normal given the fact that the `text_2` field probably has the standard index analyzer in your mapping (according to the explanation you're seeing), i.e. the only tokens that have been produced and indexed for `small red porsches` are `small`, `red` and `porsches`.

On the query side, you're probably using a shingle analyzer with `output_unigrams` set to true (default), which means that the unigram tokens will also be produced in addition to the bigrams (again according to the explanation you're seeing). Those unigrams are the only reason why you get matches at all. If you want to match on bigrams, then one solution is to use the shingle analyzer **at indexing time, too**, so that bigrams `small red` and `red porsches` can be produced and indexed as well in addition to the unigrams `small`, `red` and `porsches`.

Then at query time, the unigrams would match as well but `small red` bigram would definitely match, too. In order to only match on the bigrams, you can have another shingle analyzer just for query time whose `output_unigrams` is set to false, so that only bigrams get generated out of your search input. And in case your query only contains one single word (e.g. `porsches`), then that shingle analyzer would only generate a single unigram (because `output_unigrams_if_no_shingles` is true) and the query would still match your document. If that's not desired you can simply set `output_unigrams_if_no_shingles` to `false` in your shingle search analyzer.

Comment: I have updated the question to show that text_2 does in fact use the shingle analyzer. Both the indexing and query should be producing the unigrams and bigrams. The unigrams matching isn't a surprise, but if I'm not mistaken  the bigrams and trigrams should have to match as well.

Thanks for the feedback.